# Days left - subscription expire?

Tags: php

How can i get the number of days back when the subscription exipires?

I have "vipudlob" in my database. and it's timestamp ex. 2 month forward.?

```
<?php
$expire = strtotime("+2 months", time());
$daysback = $expire-time();
echo $daysback%3600;
?>
```

Comment: When you name it `$expire`, why it isn't the timestamp, when it expires (`$remainingSeconds = $expire - time()`)?

Comment: I need to print the amount of days back to the subscription expires.

Comment: Why didn't you included the query to your mysql? The timestamp you have stored there ..

Comment: OK, you mean `($expires - time()) / (60 * 60 * 24)` then?

Comment: Because now it's testing time. So after it works i inser the correct format. Is this correct? $days = $daysLeft/86400;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime("+2 months");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Output

```
+61 days
```