# Display days between one date and today

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find number of days between two dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php)
>   [Days left - subscription expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795088/days-left-subscription-expire)

I have code that should echo how many days has been from date (2012-10-01) to today.

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2012-10-01');
$datetime2 = date_create();

$day1 = date_format($datetime1, 'Y-m-d');
$day2 = date_format($datetime2, 'Y-m-d');    

$day = $day2 - $day1 / (60 * 60 * 24);
echo $day;
```

I cant get any right solution, so any ideas how I should do this?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: You need to convert the dates to a unix timestamp prior to performing the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/)

Sample code (for your date) below:

```
$now = time();
$your_date = strtotime('2012-10-01');
$datediff = $now - $your_date;
echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```